# How can I redirect users if using the non-rewritten url from Htaccess?

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to make it so when you access the non-written url, for example this one: website.com/profile.php?name=Alex you would get redirected to a 404 not found page. But if you would access website.com/profile/Alex it would just work normally. How could I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use these rules:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# 404 if using internal URL directly
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /profile\.php\?name= [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]

# rewrite for /profile/alex
RewriteRule ^(profile)/([\w-]+)/?$ $1.php?name=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: I do still have a problem..
Whenever calling the 404 document using this:
ErrorDocument 404 /alliance/404.php
Will only redirect to the 404 page for the first rule. So let's say I've used the thing you gave me twice, once for each page, it would only redirect me to the 404 page for the first rule in the .htaccess document. For the rest of the rules, it would redirect me to the default 404 page. The one with the "Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request." text.